# Как разобрать JSON данные методом исключения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в jQuery правильно разобрать JSON данные используя метод исключения.

Например, пользователь выбирать марку автомобиля `"Ваз"`, тогда все другие марки автомобилей исключаются. В примере ниже из массива должно остаться 3 элемента.

```
[
   {
     "mark":"Ваз",
     "model":"2101"
   },
   {
     "mark":"Ваз",
     "model":"2107"
   },
   {
     "mark":" Toyota",
     "model":"Camry"
   },
   {
     "mark":"Ваз",
     "model":"2121 Нива"
   },
   {
     "mark":"Ford",
     "model":"Focus"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Для фильтрации массивов можно использовать метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var filtered = data.filter(el=>el.mark == 'Ваз');
```

Comment: и `var filtered = data.filter(function(el){ return el.mark == 'Ваз';});` ))

Comment: @Jean-Claude, это одно и то же